# How to get around the small space in between table rows?

Tags: html, jquery, html-table, menu, cell

I am using JQuery to build a menu with table cells. Now this JQuery is a test that should only alert "hello" if I leave the 1st cell AND I have not entered the second cell. It still fires when I go from the 1st cell into the second cell. I found out that there is a TINY space in between the rows of the table which is causing the JQuery to think that I am not inside the second cell. Here is the JQuery...

```
$("#layer2_cell1").mouseenter(function() { 
$("#storage").data("2", "1");
});
$("#layer2_cell1").mouseleave(function() { 
$("#storage").data("2", "0");
});
$("#layer1_cell1").mouseenter(function() { 
$("#storage").data("1", "1");
});
$("#layer1_cell1").mouseleave(function() { 
$("#storage").data("1", "0");
var test1 = $("#storage").data("2");
if (!(test1 == "1")) {
alert("hello");
}
});
```

Here is some of the html...

```
<table align="center" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td class="leftend" background="images/box_background.jpg">
</td>
<div id="test">
<td id="layer1_cell1" class="layer1" background="images/box_background.jpg">
<font size="5" color="#01DFD7"><b>Airplanes</b></font>
</td>
</div>
<td id="layer1_cell3" class="layer1" background="images/box_background.jpg">
<font size="5" color="#01DFD7"><b>Cars</b></font>
</td>
<td id="layer1_cell4" class="layer1" background="images/box_background.jpg">
<font size="5" color="#01DFD7"><b>Cell Phones</b></font>
</td>
<td id="layer1_cell2" class="layer1" background="images/box_background.jpg">
<font size="5" color="#01DFD7"><b>Televisions</b></font>
</td>
<td id="layer1_cell5" class="layer1" background="images/box_background.jpg">
<font size="5" color="#01DFD7"><b>Other</b></font>
</td>
<td class="rightend" background="images/box_background.jpg">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="permanentlyhiddencell" class="leftend">
</td>
<td id="layer2_cell1" class="bottomcell" background="images/box_background.jpg">
<font size="5" color="#01DFD7"><b>Cessna</b></font>
</td>
<td id="layer2_cell2" class="layer2" background="images/box_background.jpg">
<font size="5" color="#01DFD7"><b>Mercedes Benz</b></font>
</td>
<td id="layer2_cell3" class="layer2" background="images/box_background.jpg">
<font size="5" color="#01DFD7"><b>LG</b></font>
</td>
<td id="layer2_cell4" class="layer2" background="images/box_background.jpg">
<font size="5" color="#01DFD7"><b>LG</b></font>
</td>
<td id="layer2_cell5" class="layer2" background="images/box_background.jpg">
<font size="5" color="#01DFD7"><b>Balloons</b></font>
</td>
</tr>
```

and the css...

```
.layer1 {
text-align:center;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#01DFD7;
border-style:solid;
border-width:2px;  
width: 150px;
height:75px;
}
.layer2 {
text-align:center;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#01DFD7;
border-style:solid;
border-width:2px;  
width: 150px;
height:75px;
}
.bottomcell {
border-bottom-left-radius:15px;
border-bottom-right-radius:15px;
text-align:center;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#01DFD7;
border-style:solid;
border-width:2px;  
width: 150px;
height:75px;
}
.rightend {
border-top-right-radius:15px;
border-bottom-right-radius:15px;
text-align:center;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#01DFD7;
border-style:solid;
border-width:2px;  
width: 30px;
height:75px;
}
.leftend {
border-top-left-radius:15px;
border-bottom-left-radius:15px;
text-align:center;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#01DFD7;
border-style:solid;
border-width:2px;  
width: 30px;
height:75px;
}
.layer1 {
text-align:center;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#01DFD7;
border-style:solid;
border-width:2px;  
width: 150px;
height:75px;
}
.layer2 {
text-align:center;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#01DFD7;
border-style:solid;
border-width:2px;  
width: 150px;
height:75px;
}
.bottomcell {
border-bottom-left-radius:15px;
border-bottom-right-radius:15px;
text-align:center;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#01DFD7;
border-style:solid;
border-width:2px;  
width: 150px;
height:75px;
}
.rightend {
border-top-right-radius:15px;
border-bottom-right-radius:15px;
text-align:center;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#01DFD7;
border-style:solid;
border-width:2px;  
width: 30px;
height:75px;
}
.leftend {
border-top-left-radius:15px;
border-bottom-left-radius:15px;
text-align:center;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#01DFD7;
border-style:solid;
border-width:2px;  
width: 30px;
height:75px;
}
```

Comment: really difficult to tell without your HTML or CSS part of code! 
why don't you put yourcode in jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

Would "a table isn't a menu so don't use it as one" qualify as a way around this? Otherwise, CSS for your table `border-collapse: collapse;` would probably do the trick.

Comment: @AllenHundley - hard to know without the HTML/CSS try playing with cellspacing, setting it to 0.  border-collapse *should* do the same thing.  But seriously, there's got to be a better way to do this than tables...nested unordered lists, perhaps?

Comment: Added the css and html. Does that help?

Comment: @AllenHundley I think the problem might simply be the ordering of the events.  The mouseleave event on the first cell fires before the mouseenter on the second.  Since JavaScript is single-threaded, you're still in the mouseleave handler and the data hasn't changed yet.

Comment: Well I tried to switch it around. Still nothing. I think it is the small space in between table rows. I only discovered this because I have the pointer to change to a finger while hovering and if I go very slowly I can see the mouse change back into default just before it turns into a pointer again.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out I could us `<tbody>` for this. I simply surrounded all my rows with a `<tbody>` tag and gave it an ID. The `<tbody>` tag only surrounds tags that are not hidden so in JQuery I just made an event that hides all the table cells if the cursor goes out of the `<tbody>`